# Scheduling .exe file to run that has excel in the program

Tags: excel, vb.net, windows-10

I have created an app in Visual Studios using VB.NET, upon load the form loads an excel spreadsheet and performs a set of tasks before saving and exiting.

I can manually run the .exe file by clicking but when i schedule it through he built in task scheduler it doesn't do anything. The task doesn't stop or error it just shows as running but never runs

I have done various searching on the net for help with this but i cant seem to find anything anywhere. I have another form that opens a text file, does its thing and then closes the text file and this works perfectly fine which is why it is confusing me so much. I have tried adding my code to the textfile one and copying the commands from the textfile task manager but it doesn't work! I came to the conclusion that it is something to do with excel as the code works fine on its own and the scheduling works fine with a form that links to a text file.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated

Code Below

```
    Dim filepath1, filepath3, colcontents, rowcontents, txtfile As String
        Dim objExcel, objworkbook As Object
        Dim coln, rown, rowval As Integer
        Dim obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        txtfile = FULLFILEPATH
        filepath1 = FULLFILEPATH
        filepath3 = FULLFILEPATH
        filepath3 = FULLFILEPATH
        'Define as getfile filepath
        Dim objfile = obj.getfile(filepath1)
        If ran = False Then
            objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            objExcel.visible = False
            rown = 2
            coln = 1
            colcontents = "Text"
            objworkbook = objExcel.workbooks.open(filepath1)
            objExcel.sheets("KPIStock").activate
            Do Until colcontents = ""
                colcontents = objExcel.cells(1, coln).text
                coln = coln + 1
            Loop
            colvalglo = coln
            rown = 1
            rowcontents = "Text"
            'Counts the number of rows that have data in them
            Do Until rowcontents = ""
                rowcontents = objExcel.cells(rown, 1).text
                rown = rown + 1
                rowval = rown
            Loop
            rowvalglo = rowval
            MsgBox("Limits Found")
If obj.FileExists(filepath4) Then
            'If the file exists then delete it
            obj.DeleteFile(filepath4)
        Else
        End If
        'Pass values to set variables
        colcontents = "Text"
        param1 = Nothing
        param2 = Nothing
        'Define the object as getting a file from the selected filepath
        Dim objfile = obj.getfile(filepath1)
        objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objExcel.visible = False
        'Open selected file
        objworkbook = objExcel.workbooks.open(filepath1)
        colnc = 9
        count = 1
        'Loop until there are no column contents and then save this column number into a global variable
        Do Until colcontents = ""
            rown = 2
            'Activate the Parameteres sheet
            objExcel.sheets("Parameters").activate
            colcontents = objExcel.cells(rown, colnc).text
            'Set Param1 equal to what is contained in the parameters sheet and cells
            param1 = objExcel.cells(rown, colnc).text
            rown = 3
            'Set Param2 equal to what is contained in the parameters sheet and cells
            param2 = objExcel.cells(rown, colnc).text
            objExcel.sheets("KPIStock").activate
            colpaste = colvalglo - 1
            'Header
            rown = 1
            'Save the contents of the cell into the selected Variable
            objExcel.cells(rown, colpaste).value = param1
            'Formula
            rown = 2
            'Save the contents of the cell into the selected Variable
            objExcel.cells(rown, colpaste).value = param2
            'Increase various variables by 1
            colnc = colnc + 1
            colpaste = colpaste + 1
            colvalglo = colvalglo + 1
            count = count + 1
        Loop
        rowvalglo = rowvalglo - 2
        'Copy all of added data and paste to the bottom
        With objExcel
            .range(.cells(2, colvalglo - count), .cells(2, colvalglo)).copy
            .range(.cells(2, colvalglo - count), .cells(rowvalglo, colvalglo)).pastespecial
        End With
        'Set specific cell range to a certain colour
        With objExcel
            .range(.cells(1, colvalglo - count), .cells(1, colvalglo - 65)).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LightCyan)
        End With
        'Set specific cell range to a certain colour
        With objExcel
            .range(.cells(2, colvalglo - count), .cells(rowvalglo, colvalglo - 65)).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LightYellow)
        End With
        'Set specific cell range to a certain colour
        With objExcel
            .range(.cells(1, colvalglo - 65), .cells(1, colvalglo - 30)).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LightGreen)
        End With
        'Set specific cell range to a certain colour
        With objExcel
            .range(.cells(2, colvalglo - 65), .cells(rowvalglo, colvalglo - 30)).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LightSalmon)
        End With
        'Set specific cell range to a certain colour
        With objExcel
            .range(.cells(1, colvalglo - 30), .cells(1, colvalglo - 3)).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LightSteelBlue)
        End With
        'Set specific cell range to a certain colour
        With objExcel
            .range(.cells(2, colvalglo - 30), .cells(rowvalglo, colvalglo - 3)).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.GhostWhite)
        End With
        'Copy all of added data and paste as values
        With objExcel
            .range(.cells(2, colvalglo - count), .cells(rowvalglo, colvalglo)).copy
            .range(.cells(2, colvalglo - count), .cells(rowvalglo, colvalglo)).Pastespecial(-4163, -4142, True, False)
        End With
        'Save Output workbook to Filepath4
        objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(filepath4)
        objworkbook.Close
        objExcel.Quit
        objExcel = Nothing
        objworkbook = Nothing
        'Set updated Boolean to TRUE
        updated = True
        rowval = rowval + 1
        'Display message box informating the task has now been complete and to review as required
        MsgBox("Defined columns have now been added, please review")
```

Comment: it could well be. Are you using COM interop to access Excel? This is often a bit flakey if running as an automated process. It was never intended for that. Better to use a library which interacts directly with the Excel file itself (as opposed to the application). But that's only speculation. You perhaps need to add better logging / debug output to your application so you can see what is actually going wrong with it. And also show us some relevant code, so we can what you're doing, and how you're doing it.

Comment: Full code now added :-)

Comment: Ok, as I suspected, you're interacting with Excel the application, not the Excel file. So you're automating Excel actions as if the user had it open on screen in front of them. This is not a scenario suited to being run as a scheduled task, which of course is a non-human-user environment. Chances are it hangs or crashes somewhere (I've got experience of this in a very old app I had to maintain and was trying to do something similar). Also using a GUI tool such as MsgBox in a non-user environment doesn't make much sense either, you'd be better writing to a log file or something.

Comment: I don't know if you're working with .xls or .xlsx files, but online you can find libraries which interact with each directly by opening the file itself, and does not depend on the Excel application. My advice would be to re-write the code using one of those. If you're using .xlsx you'll probably have an easier time finding a good one (and also a free once, since the file format itself is open).

Comment: Thanks for the info, yes i am using .xlsx.

Comment: The message box was there when i am running the form in .NET and just forgot to take it out when posting in here, its not in the published version the task scheduler is trying to use

Comment: I dont currently have any experience of working with libraries in that way at all so i will see what i can find on the net :-)